# Reference for the hadith "Allah shall destroy a nation if evil exceeds good"?

Tags: hadith, reference-request

There is a hadith where Nabi SAW says that Allah shall destroy a nation if evil exceeds good in that nation. Then Sahaba RA asked Nabi SAW whether Allah shall destroy the nation even if it contains good and pious person, the reply was yes again if evil exceeds goodness.

What is the reference of this hadith?

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to one of these ahadith?

> - "Messenger of Allah! Shall we be destroyed while there are people who are salih among us?" The Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, "Yes, if there is much wickedness." (Muwatta' [Malik](https://sunnah.com/urn/518150))
> - There is no being worthy of worship except Allah; there is a destruction in store for Arabia because of turmoil which is at hand, the barrier of Gog and Magog has opened so much. And Sufyan made a sign of ten with the help of his hand (in order to indicate the width of the gap) and I said: Allah's Messenger, would we be perished in spite of the fact that there would be good people amongst us? Thereupon he said: Of course, but only when the evil predominates.
>   (Several versions sahih Muslim [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/54/1) -the one posted above- and [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/54/3), sahih al-Bukhari [1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/106), [2](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/92/11) and [3](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3346), Jami' [at-Tirmdihi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/28) and sunan [ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/28))

Comment: that's it bro, Jazak Allah !!